# SQL Server - Where are linked server details/files located

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I am trying to find my old linked server details to transfer to a new server. Normally if I had access via management studio I would script the linked server but I only have access to the file system of the corrupted server. I can see program files/sql etc and other places but I am not sure where to look. I also have access to msdb database if they are saved there.

Answer (score 1):

They are in system tables in the `master` database.  If you have a test SQL Server at exactly the same version/service pack/CU you can shut it down and copy over the `master.mdf` and `master.ldf` and start it.  Then you can query the system views like [`sys.servers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-servers-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), etc.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, can you advise where exactly ?

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: you are correct indeed but I have issues restoring the master from a .bak file

Comment: And what "issues" would those be? No one can see your screen or read your mind. Did you encounter an error? Do you not have a backup to restore? Something else?

Comment: Using the master.mdf/master.ldf is an alternative to restoring a backup of master.